# "Take it easy on" vs "take it easy with"

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference between "take it easy on" and "take it easy with"? For example, which of the following is correct:

> Take it easy on me.
>
> Take it easy with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are maybe mixing up two different expressions.

According to the [Cambridge Dctionaary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-it-easy), the expression **take it easy** measn **rest, relax, stay calm**.

> Take it easy with me

means **let's you and I relax together**.

You would only use **on** when specifying a day, for example

> Take it easy on Sunday.

The expression that you are probably looking for is **[go easy on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-easy-on-someone)**, which means **to treat someone in a gentle way, esp. when you want to be or should be more severe**

So, if you have done something bad and you want somebody to be lenient with you, you could say

> Go easy on me.